# Can I create mini-WordPresses on my WordPress?

Tags: blog

... or what is the best way to do this?

I want to use my WordPress blog and create blogs for a few people on it. So they would create posts and it would post to their own "website" like mysite.com/JohnPeavy/new-post-1 and so they wouldn't be bothered by all my posts or eachothers (like in "all posts") or see any of the plugins or technical stuff. I just want them to be able to blog on my website with their own blog kind of thing.

Has anyone done this / know a few good places I can see how its done / know the best way to proceed with this?

Thanks, JM

Comment: Setup multisite. There are thousands of resources on the net on how to setup a network like wordpress.com

Comment: Is this kind of like what Facebook did early on? I was hearing a friend talk about how Facebook was in 2007 (I never saw it then) and apparently you could customize your page and things)?

Comment: Also did not know facebook early on, but like I said, use the multisite feature. This way you can have thousands of separate blogs on one install, works the same way as the blogs hosted on wordpress.com

Comment: I was looking at multisite today. I think I may go this route. Is it possible for new users to come to a page and "sign up" for their own "account" sort of like Facebook does (rather than manually configuring them for each one). So when I bring on someone new, they can just go to that page, "sign up" fill out their information in fields, and it gets automatically made (if approved) like Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

as many people said here, multisite is one option for you. But... I am not recommending it. The problem here is that multisite is huge hardly managable, have problems with users management and security features. I have lots of problems with multisites.

**1) You can have more wordpress sites in one hosting.**

Simply make folder on your hosting, copy new wordpress in it, set domain alias and .htaccess to that folder and you are done. You have new, separate site and when you need to get rid of it, you simply delete database and this folder with it. Opposite of multisite, those two or more sites will be separated totally. With this, you need to install plugins separately and do everything separately. Multisite can be managed from multisite settings and plugins together for them all.

**2) Custom sites.**

You can have more sites on one wordpress. You just need to program it. Nobody tells you that you can not do separate categories, values for separate users and everything. So when you make theme, you can easily do separate theme settings for pages etc. Everything will be in one site, you just need to play a bit around it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Somewhat helps. I'm aware of multiple websites in hosting, but I don't want to create a new site for each user. That would defeat the purpose. I do custom sites, but I don't want separate page themes, I want my users to have their own little blog inside my WordPress site.